# standalonetrue / standalonefalse?

Tags: conditionals, standalone

You can use `\standalonefalse` to specify the parent document for which all sub-documents should be considered sub-documents, I think.

Is it possible to re-enable `standalone` with something like `\standalonetrue` after a `\standalonefalse` call?

I would like this capability because I have a paper that uses standalone for its subsections that is being included in a thesis, which also uses standalone.  I'd like to be able to compile the chapter, the paper, and the thesis each independently (since each document has different dependencies / build times).

EDIT: MWE below and here: https://gist.github.com/keflavich/5224790 (because there are multiple file interdependencies, I figured it was best to have a complete example in one place).

My understanding of both latex conditionals and standalone must be pretty weak.  I've constructed a MWE (`sub2.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
%\standalonetrue
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Nothing here (but I want to compile this document on its own sometimes)
\citet{Aguirre2010}
\ifstandalone
\bibliographystyle{apj_w_etal}  
\bibliography{mwe}      
\fi
\end{document}
```

with `mwe.bib`:

```
@article{Aguirre2010,
    title={Title},
    author = {Aguirre},
    journal = {In Prep},
    year={2010}
}
```

If I compile this code with `pdflatex sub2.tex && bibtex sub2`, it gives me bibtex problems:

```
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file sub2.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file sub2.aux
```

If I uncomment `\standalonetrue`, it works.

The problem comes in if I have another document that `import`s this document.  In order to compile this document, I need `\standalonetrue` in it.  But the parent document (below), won't accept an imported document with `\standalonetrue` in it, as far as I can tell:

```
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 8 of file sub1.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {apj_w_etal}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibdata command---line 9 of file sub1.aux
 : \bibdata
 :         {mwe}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

Here's the "parent" document (called `sub1.tex`)

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\usepackage{standalone}
\standalonetrue
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter of an Article}
This is an article that includes many subsections
\subimport{./}{sub2}
\ifstandalone
\bibliographystyle{apj_w_etal}
\bibliography{mwe}      
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use `\input{preface}` in MWEs. It defeats the purpose of a MWE because your preamble isn't shown. Note that I'm not 100% sure what you exactly mean with "uses standalone". You mean the class or the package?

Comment: I'm using the package, not the class.  And I intentionally did not try to include a complete MWE - it would take too long at this point.

Comment: I still can't understand your exact use-case. There is nothing in your example for which you need `standalone`.

Comment: I've updated the example to create a genuine MWE now; I can't include a standalone inside another standalone because of 1-bibdata-per-file restrictions.

Answer (score 11):

I'm the author of `standalone`. The `\ifstandalone` switch is defined automatically by both the package and the class, in different form, to indicate if a subfile is compiled stand-alone or as part of a main document. The switch is not designed to be modified by the user and I acutally have to look at the source code again to be able to tell which impact doing so would have. It's definitifly not a supported feature and so I wouldn't recommend it.

Note that you can include `standlone` documents inside another `standalone` documents, i.e. use the `standalone` package in a `standalone` class document. That *is* a supported feature. You don't need to change any switches for this. If you want to compile the subfiles by themselves simply use them as main documents.

The main document is not selected by any switches, but simply by you, i.e. with document you feed to your LaTeX compiler. It seems to me that you are using some graphical LaTeX develop environment/editor and don't specify there which document it should compile. This is a setting of this specific program and has nothing to do with the LaTeX code itself. If you tell us which program you are using people should be able to help you with it. I personally use the command line a lot.

Comment: I'm using the command line only... I think there must be some strange behavior going on, then.  I'll try to construct a MWE.

Comment: I still don't really understand this answer.  If I compile my

Comment: @keflavich: I had issues understanding your question as well. It looks to me that you misunderstood the function of the if-switch. Users are not supposed to use `\standalonetrue` by themselves. It is set by both the `standalone` class and package - to different settings - and is intended to be able to exclude or include code inside a subfile depending on whether it is compiled by itself or as part of a main document.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, and sorry... I meant not to send that comment.  My issue is, I can't get my bibliographies to include with `\ifstandalone` unless specifying it explicitly.  I think the problem is having doubly-nested standalone files.